# Google Chrome split screen tabs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, window, split-window

I'm not sure if I stumbled upon functionality or just coincidence... But I can't seem to recreate the move. I started with two tabs in Google Chrome next to each other and using just the trackpad I was able to move one tab another window perfectly split screen vertically. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that natively, beyond manual window sizing and positioning, but there are several applications and Chrome extensions that will let you accomplish that or similar effects.

**Mac Apps**

- [Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy/)
- [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt)
- [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)

**Chrome extensions**

- [Tab Resize](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-resize-split-screen-l/bkpenclhmiealbebdopglffmfdiilejc)
- [Split Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/split-tabs/mamepagkigmnpoalafajabnljlkkocbk?hl=en)